# Number of reducer in map reduce

Tags: hadoop

I have set 3 reducer in driver class in MR.

it means three partitions will be created..

but mapper is emiting only two unique key say male and female.

In this case, how times Reducer and reduce functions will run?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but I could come up with two explanations of what may happen:

## 1. Two stage reduction

- Reducer 1 reduces all male results
- Reducer 2 reduces all female
  results
- Resucer 3 reduces the output of Reducer 1 and 2.

## 2. Splitting a job

- Reducer 1 reduces all male results
- Reducer 2 reduces the first half of female results
- Reducer 3 reduces the second half of female results

Comment: hi Dennis ,

thanks for your answer.
but I think number of reducer depends on number of unique key emitting by mapper.

Answer (score 1):

If you set 3 reducers they will all run. However, if you only have two keys at *most* two of the reducers will actually receive data to process.

Comment: it means only two reducer will run, one for male and one for female .right?

 Similarly if 3 reducer is set and mapper is emitting 4 unique key then how many reducer would run?

Comment: No, if you tell it to run 3 reducers, 3 will run. At least 1 of them will not receive any data (in the two key case) and run very quickly. You control how many reducers run, the partitioner will control how the keys are divided up between the number you set.

Comment: Mr Nerd,

if 3 reducer is set  in driver class and mapper is emitting 4 unique key then how many reducer would run?

Comment: 3 would run. How these keys are divided up between the reducers is down to the partitioner.

Comment: ok. so the fourth key will also be processed by any one of three reducer. right?