# Hadoop Map Reduce - Number of Reducer

Tags: mapreduce, reducers, partitioner

I have use case that has data of employee of a company of different age group.
I need to find highest salary of male and female employee of three age group category.

for detail pls go to below link -

http://www.myhadoopexamples.com/2014/03/01/hadoop-mapreduce-example-with-partitioner/

My question is - Here we have only two key emited by mapper i.e male and female.
and we have set 3 reducer in driver class thus 3 partition will be created.

There could be two below things -

1. 3 reducer will be running for each 3 partition which inturn find out
   max female and male salary in each partioner. and gives expected result as    shown in above link.
2. Only reducer will be running actually , one of male and one for female and do the calculation

Comment: What u want exactly??

Comment: How many reducer will created at run time ? will it create 3 reducer and server data of each partitioner at a time and process the output   or just 2 reducer as only two keys are there by mapper.

Comment: Isn't this the third time in about 24 hours this question has been asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972288/number-of-reducer-in-map-reduce and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983319/number-of-reducer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the real num of reducers, you'd better run it on cluster.

As said in [Number of reducer in map reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972288/number-of-reducer-in-map-reduce), it will launch 3 reducers and 1 reducer will process no data. If you want to use all three reducers, you may change the Partioner class, like partitioning data by the age group